# How to create a report based on multiple tables?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Here is the setup:

1. I have a database with about 7 tables. one of table (`tblUsers`) stores the names of the users of the database while the `other six tables` are used to store information inputted by the users of the database. with that I have a one-to-many relationship between the `tblUsers` and all the other tables in the database showing `"ALL records from 'tblUsers' and only those records from 'OtherTable' where the joined fields are equal."`
2. I have created a form (`frmReport`)with a combobox select a user from tblUsers and two text box that will allow me to select a date range.

Here is what I would like to accomplish: I would like to create a report that will return information from all the six tables based on criteria in the form.

> PS. Im able to create the a report based on two tables eg. tblUsers and one other table, but whenever I have more that 2 table that's when I'm confused. I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use one query with multiple `LEFT JOIN`s such as:

```
SELECT tblUsers.*, tblA.*, tblB.*, tblC.*, tblD.*, tblE.*, tblF.*
FROM tblUsers
LEFT JOIN tblA ON tblUsers.pk=tblA.fk
LEFT JOIN tblB ON tblUsers.pk=tblB.fk
LEFT JOIN tblC ON tblUsers.pk=tblC.fk
LEFT JOIN tblD ON tblUsers.pk=tblD.fk
LEFT JOIN tblE ON tblUsers.pk=tblE.fk
LEFT JOIN tblF ON tblUsers.pk=tblF.fk
```

The `LEFT JOIN` includes only records from the first table and records that match on the second table.    In this case I refer to pk as the primary key in tblUsers, and fk as the associated foreign key in the other tables.  You can replace your table names in this query example, of course.

This will create one long record associated with each user in the tblUser table, but no records not matching the user.

Comment: Interesting... Im going to give it a try now by using the query builder. then switch to sql view and modify it to look like that.

Comment: I used the query builder to create your suggestion and I'm getting a lot of duplication. how do i prevent the duplication of records in the query?

Comment: I am not sure in what way your are getting duplicates; can you give a better example of your code in your question?  It can get complicated, but you can always consider `GROUP BY` or using sub-queries. However, the latter you need to be careful that you are not eliminating possibly good data.

Comment: turning on `GROUP BY` prevented the duplication only when I'm using two tables in the query builder. eg tblUsers and one other table. However, if I add a third table I start getting duplication. What do I do to prevent this?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is not possible, even if you add the `DISTINCT` keyword after your SELECT statement;  If you think about it, you are ASKING for duplication of data.  How else would it report, for a given user, multiple records in tblA and tblB?  Try to hand type your expected output, you will see what I mean; it is impossible to write it out without duplicate information.  Each COMPLETE line will be unique, but may have only one field different from another line.

Comment: I really looked into what you said Sable Foste and you are so right.